# Removable or essential singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$cos(1-z^{-1})$$

We can see that the Laurent expansion of this function will contain infinity terms of the form $a/z^{n}$, so following this reasoning, the singularity z=0 is essential.

*But $1>=|cos(1-z^{-1})|$, so the function is bounded. A boundedness behaviour is a characteristic of removable singularities, so we conclude the singularity z=0 is removable.*

I had these two thought while trying to characterizing the singularity of this function. After seeing the answer, apparently the italic sentence is false, since the singularity is essential. But what is the falsity of this sentence? Why is it wrong?

Comment: It is not true that $|\cos(z)|<=1$ for complex values of $z$. For example, if $z$ is pure imaginary, say $z = ix$, then $\cos z = \cosh x$, which is unbounded.

Comment: If $\cos(z)$ was bounded then it would be constant by Liouville's theorem. (which is clearly not the case)